# Django, Response using List of Dict

Tags: python, django

I'm looking to be able for response using list of dict like following

```
bio_dict = [{'subject' : 'Name', 'value' : 'MyName'},\
    {'subject' : 'Birth Date', 'value' : '1998-1-1'},\
    {'subject' : 'Sex', 'value' : 'M'}]

def index(request):
    response = { bio_dict['subject'] : bio_dict['value'] }
    return render(request, 'page.html', response)
```

but that response return:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Using python 3.6 and django 1.11

Comment: `bio_dict` is a list, not a  dict

Comment: Why is your bio_dict not just `{'Name': 'MyName', 'Birth Date': '1998...}`?

Comment: Because i want bio_dict as a table, for example an additional 'attribue' tag,

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the fact that you call

```
bio_dict['subject'] and bio_dict['value']
```

but `bio_dict` is a list. This is the syntax to access a dictionary not a list.

Now, in order to have an output like you wanted, you could use dict comprehension like so,

```
response = {item['subject']:item['value'] for item in bio_dict}
```

that way you have a similar syntax of what you tried, but now you iterate on each dict in `bio_dict` and accessing them instead.

Answer (score 0):

So if you look at `bio_dict`, its a list, and as the exception says, list indices must be integers or slices.

By doing -
`bio_dict['subject']` 
you are essentially passing a string as list index.

You will first need to access the list like -

`bio_dict[0]` and by doing this, you will be able to access the dictionaries that the list contains.

And since there are three dicts int the list, `bio_dict[0]` will give you the first dict which is -

`{'subject' : 'Name', 'value' : 'MyName'`

and `bio_dict[1]` will get you the second dict which is -

`{'subject' : 'Birth Date', 'value' : '1998-1-1'}`

and so on.

You can access the dict elements by -

`bio_dict[0]['subject']`

and so on.

Depending on the use case, you could use a loop like -

```
for dict in list:
    for key, value in dict.iteritems():
    # do something with key or value
```

Comment: Accessing dict one by one is actually far from optimal.

Comment: @scharette no doubt about that. This is just to explain how they can be accessed.

Comment: Well you clearly imply that he should be using an index based solution to access the list, which is bad practice.

Comment: I do not understand how I am implying that meanwhile all I am doing is trying to make him understand how we can access lists and dictionaries. Added a for loop example as well.

Answer (score 0):

try to just pass `dict` instead full key and values . See [Variables and lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups)

```
bio_dict = {
              'name' : 'MyName', 
              'birth_date': '1998-1-1',
              'sex' : 'M'
           }

def index(request):
    response = { bio_dict: 'bio_dict' }
    return render(request, 'page.html', response)
```

and in your template page.html , to render the value in html template use:

```
{% for my_key, my_value in bio_dict.items %}

  <p> {{ my_key }} : {{ my_value }} </p>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This page.html is like what i needed but with `bio_dict: 'bio_dict'`,I got  `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: @dika_saja ,  The problem is that you can't use a list as the key in a dict, since dict keys need to be immutable. i´ve EDIT my answer to adress what you need. have a try.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, `bio_dict` is a list, not a dictionary.
If you want to create a context dict `response` for your view, you can do it like the following:

```
bio_dict = [{'subject' : 'Name', 'value' : 'MyName'},\
{'subject' : 'Birth Date', 'value' : '1998-1-1'},\
{'subject' : 'Sex', 'value' : 'M'}]
```

```
def index(request):
   response = {}
   for item in bio_dict:
        # populate response = {}
        response[item['subject']] = item['value']
   return render(request, 'page.html', response)
```